# Inetsim log not generating a report

Tags: malware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g544G.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qXZj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skcm3.jpg)I noticed when I stop the inetsim log, and move to the /var/log/inetsim/report/ directory there is no report listed, I have my Fake DNS running and it is indeed collecting traffic from the malware on my Windows machine and the default gateway is set to my Remnux machine. Both machines are reachable since they both passed my ping test. I would love to hear some ideas as to why the report is not being generated.

I tried stopping the scans re-running the malware from the machine enabling the content to generate new traffic and re-configuring the IP addresses.

Comment: Please share logs as text, not image.